# show org-mode outline up to a certain heading level

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm making an outline for my thesis using org-mode, and I'd like to show all headings up to a certain level (e.g. all level-1 and level-2 headings).

I haven't found anything about that in the org-mode manual. Cycling shows either only level-1 headings, or all headings, which is too much information in my outline right now.

Thanks,

daniel.

**Update:** I found a workaround for his: set the variable org-cycle-max-level. This is a global setting, though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just stumbled on this question. One year later but what the heck.. There are commands for this that allows you to show headings to a certain level.

One command is `C-<n> C-c tab` will show subheadings up to level `<n>` `(<n>=1,2,3...)`.

Another command is `C-<n> S-tab` which will operate on the whole buffer. It shows all headings up to level `<n>` `(<n>=1,2,3...)`

Comment: @Whil I fully agree with Andrew; however, the second command does not work for me, `C-tab` is bound to `org-force-cycle-archived`.

Comment: @danielkullmann Sorry - should be `C-<n> S-tab`. Edited above for clarity.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this by default when opening the file? The options [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html) seem to be all or nothing.

Comment: @ElliottSlaughter See here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12938/how-can-i-evaluate-elisp-in-an-orgmode-file-when-it-is-opened

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution that suits me: The command org-content shows the folder hierarchy, and giving it a numeric argument does exactly what I want: limit the maximum level shown. In my example, I wanted to show 2 levels, so I can do `C-2 M-x org-content <RET>`.

I also added my own command to my `.emacs` init file, binding that command to C-c m

```
(defun org-show-two-levels ()
  (interactive)
  (org-content 2))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key org-mode-map "\C-cm" 'org-show-two-levels)))
```

Comment: `org-content` works on the whole buffer - why is often what you want. If you are want to operate on the subtree under the point then you can use `show-children` in an identical fashion.

Comment: More generally, one should appreciate that `org-mode` is build upon `outline-mode`, so you can use many of its display functions (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Visibility.html)

Answer (score 2):

I am way late to the party, but let us add a simple way for posterity.  Simply use `Cycle Global Visibility (<backtab>)`. If your headings are open, it will close them.  However, if you apply it repeatedly with all headings collapsed, they will open to the level you want.

I use it from the keyboard by `<SHIFT>`+`<TAB>`.  You can also find it in the Org menu (in Emacs) under Show/Hide -> Cycle Global Visibility ()

Comment: Welcome to the party!

Answer (score 1):

If the prefix arguments from M. Kullman's answer take too much mental capacity for you (a limited resource when you are thinking hard about something else at the same time) then you can use the following functions to expand contract headings

```
(defvar hf-org-depth-point nil)
(defvar hf-org-depth-depth nil)

(defun hf-org-depth-increase ()
   (interactive)
   (hf-org-depth-incr 1))

(defun hf-org-depth-decrease ()
    (interactive)
    (hf-org-depth-incr -1))

(defun hf-org-depth-incr (incr)
    (when (not (equal (point) hf-org-depth-point))
        (setq hf-org-depth-point nil)
        (setq hf-org-depth-depth 0))a
    (setq hf-org-depth-point (point))
    (setq hf-org-depth-depth (max (+ hf-org-depth-depth incr) 0))
    (hide-subtree)
    (show-children hf-org-depth-depth))
```

```